# ANDROID EMULATOR with NFC Broadcom middleware STACK

Tags: sdk, stack, emulation, nfc, broadcom

I want to connect NFC firmware to Android Emulator running with newly arrived Broadcom Stack.

But I could not find any NFC related settings or modules in the default emulators provided by the SDK version 4.2 (API 17) downloaded onto Eclipse.

Can some one help me out or give details whether this functionality with **NFC Broadcom stack is available in any emulator**?